# Не видит функцию С# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Я создал скрипт C# в котором есть несколько функций и функция ChooseResolution().
Прицепил его на пустой объект UIManager, который засунул в поле для объектов в обработке клика на кнопку в инспекторе. Пытаюсь выбрать фунцию ChooseResolution для выполнения, но её нету в списке, хотя все остальные функции того скрипта есть.
Из-за чего это вообще? Буду рад любой помощи.
Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool MenuActive = false;

    public GameObject[] ArrayMenus = new GameObject[5];

    private GameObject _current_menu;

    private int _index;

    //Resolution
    private string _resolution = "1920x1280" ;
    private GameObject _pre_resolution_button;

    public void MenuOpen()
    {
        if( !MenuActive )
        {
            ArrayMenus[0].SetActive(true);
            MenuActive = true;

            _current_menu = ArrayMenus[1];
        }
    }

    public void MenuClose()
    {
        if(MenuActive)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ArrayMenus.Length; ++i )
                if (i == 1) ArrayMenus[1].SetActive(true);
                else ArrayMenus[i].SetActive(false);     

            MenuActive = false;

            _current_menu = null;
        }
    }

    public void OpenNewTab(GameObject Tab)
    {
        _current_menu.SetActive(false);
        Tab.SetActive(true);

        _current_menu = Tab;
    }

    public void Back(GameObject Menu)
    {
        _current_menu.SetActive(false);
        Menu.SetActive(true);

        _current_menu = Menu;

    }

    public void ExitYes()
    {
        if (MenuActive && _current_menu == ArrayMenus[3]) Application.Quit();
    }

    public void ChooseResolution(string Resolution, GameObject Button)
    {
        _resolution = Resolution;

        UnityEngine.UI.ColorBlock colorBlock = new UnityEngine.UI.ColorBlock
        {
            normalColor = new Color(27, 182, 57),
            highlightedColor = new Color(36, 66, 156),
            pressedColor = new Color(22, 44, 106)
        };

        //_pre_resolution_button;
        Button.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().colors = colorBlock;


        //Button;

        _pre_resolution_button = Button;
    }

    public void ApplyResolution()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Инспектор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, не поддерживаются методы с несколькими аргументами?

Comment: Как это посмотреть?

Comment: Измените метод ChooseResolution - вместо двух аргументов что бы он имел один. И проверьте, появится ли метод в списке.

В доках Юнити к компоненту Button не нашел информации о моей догадке, но, возможно, так и есть - Button видит только публичные методы максимум с одним аргументом (но это не точно, догадки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Базовый инспектор Unity для Button не умеет обрабатывать методы, которые имеют больше двух аргументов. Другими словами, вам придётся либо использовать кнопки, либо отказаться от этого крайне неудобного способа :)

В разработке использовать данный способ подписки на события крайне неудобно:

Во-первых - вы инкапсуляцию нарушаете. Этот метод больше никому, кроме этого класса не нужен по сути, а вы его публичным делаете, вместо того, чтобы оставить приватным.

Во-вторых - во время отладки вы не сможете узнать из какого именно места вызвался код, который вызывается из редактора. Через условных пару месяцев вы можете забыть что и где там добавляли и в итоге будете очень долго искать в чём проблема.

В-третьих - этот вызов происходит через запоминание имени метода и вызова его по нему, что медленнее и к тому же останется даже если вы сделаете метод приватным и не удалите этот вызов у кнопки. Что ещё раз усложнит отладку, если вы вдруг решите что-то переделать.

Лучшим решением тут будет использовать подписку на событие кнопки внутри самого класса. Кнопка обладает событием `onClick`, которое срабатывает при нажатии на неё. Вы можете подписаться на него прямо из кода, взяв ссылку на кнопку.

В вашем случае, вам было бы лучшее вообще написать отдельный класс конкретно под кнопку-разрешения :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, за замечания.